# Calculating limit using MacLaurin series

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion

I'm asked to calculate the following limit using Maclaurin series.

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\left(1 + x\right)^{1/x} - e} { x}$$

They say that a good piece of advice is this: $f(x)^g(x) = e^{g(x)  \log(f(x)}$

My work:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\left(1 + x\right)^{1/x} - e} { x}&=\frac{e^{\frac1x\log(1+x)} - e} { e^{\log(x)} }\\\\
&=\frac{1 + \frac1x\log(1+x) - e} { 1 + \log(x)}
\end{align}$$

??? Now what? I have been struggling with this exercise for two days, haha. (Working full time though)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: what's the limit again?

Comment: You should get $e^{\frac{\log (x+1)}{x}}\approx e-\frac{e x}{2}$ in the numerator... Don't touch the denominator, BTW

Comment: @EulerWannabe Happy New Year! I hope you're staying safe and doing well during the pandemic. I've reached out to contact you a few times, but am unsure whether you've received the notes? If you would, please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. And feel free to up vote an answer as you see fit. ;-)

Comment: @EulerWannabe Hi! It's been a while. I hope you're staying safe and healthy during the pandemic. I've reached out to contact you a few times, but am unsure whether you've received the notes? If you would, please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. And feel free to up vote an answer as you see fit. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Well, writing $\left(1+x\right)^{1/x}=e^{\frac1x\log(1+x)}$ was fine.  But writing $x=e^{\log(x)}$, while correct, doesn't facilitate the analysis.

So, let's use the Taylor Series $\log(1+x)=x-\frac12x^2+O(x^3)$ and $e^x=1+x+O(x^2)$ and write

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\left(\left(1+x\right)^{1/x}-e\right)}{x}&=\frac{e^{\frac1x\log\left(1+x\right)}-e}{x}\\\\
&=\frac{e^{\frac1x\left(x-\frac12x^2+O(x^3)\right)}-e}{x}\\\\
&=e\,\left(\frac{e^{-\frac12x+O(x^2)}-1}{x}\right)\\\\
&=e\,\left(\frac{-\frac12x+O(x^2)}{x}\right)\\\\
\end{align}$$

Can you finish now?

Comment: @EulerWannabe Hi! It's been a while. I hope you're staying safe and healthy during the pandemic. I've reached out to contact you a few times, but am unsure whether you've received the notes? If you would, please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. And feel free to up vote an answer as you see fit. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The Taylor development will turn the denominator to a polynomial (plus a remainder). There is no reason to transform the denominator, which is already a polynomial.

Now,

$$(1+x)^{1/x}=e^{\log(1+x)/x}=e^{(x-x^2/2+x^3/3\cdots)/x}=e^{1-x/2+x^2/3\cdots}=e\cdot e^{-x/2+x^2/3\cdots}
\\=e\left(1+\left(-\frac x2+\frac{x^2}3-\cdots\right)+\frac12\left(-\frac x2+\frac{x^2}3-\cdots\right)^2+\cdots\right)$$

and

$$\frac{(1+x)^{1/x}-e}x=e\frac{-\dfrac x2+O(x^2)}x.$$

Comment: Hi Yves.  How is this different from mine. ;-)

Comment: @MarkViola: it is not. Initially I just wanted to stress the polynomial issue, and the rest came automatically.

Comment: No worry Yves.  We're friends here.  I hope that you are doing well and staying safe and healthy.

Comment: No problem on my side, I acknowledge that I should have better compared. Same to you. (I was tempted to try the generalized binomial development, but not sure this leads anywhere.)